# How to send email via controller with MVC

Tags: php

I haven't sent email using MVC before and am getting a bit stuck.

In my app folder, I have a libraries folder which has Controller.php, Core.php, Database.php and I created Email.php

In Email.php I have a class:

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require '../vendor/autoload.php';

class Email {

    public function sendMail()
    {


        $mail = new PHPMailer(true);                              // Passing `true` enables exceptions
        try {
            //Server settings
            $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;                                 // Enable verbose debug output
            $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
            $mail->Host = 'mail.example.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
            $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
            $mail->Username = 'mail@example.com';                 // SMTP username
            $mail->Password = 'secret';                           // SMTP password
            $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
            $mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to

            //Recipients
            $mail->setFrom('mail@example.com');
            $mail->addAddress('someone@example.com');     // Add a recipient              // Name is optional
            $mail->addReplyTo('mail@example.com');


            //Content
            $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
            $mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
            $mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
            $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

            $mail->send();
            echo 'Message has been sent';
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo 'Message could not be sent.';
            echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
        }   
    }
}
```

I am now trying to trigger the sending of the email when I access the email view. However, I don't know what to put in the controller. The code below gives me an error.

```
public function email()
{

    $this->sendMail();
    $this->view('pages/email');
}
```

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Pages::sendMail()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create an instance of the class Email:

```
$email = new Email();
$email->sendMail();
```